# Read appsettings.json from Main project in DBContext Class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ef-code-first, .net-6.0

I have a question. Is it possible to read the appsettings.json File in the DbContext class of another class library? I tried to write an AppSettingsService.cs to read the content of appsettings.json which I then injected into another Service where I need content from the appsettings.json File. But somehow it's not possible to inject a Service into the DbContext class. What I mean with impossible is that I cannot create Migrations and apply them to the Database then

What I'm expecting is: I want to read the appsettings from my main ASP.NET Web Api project in the DbContext class of a C# Class library. Also it would be great to choose which appsettings.json file is used depending on the profile. F.e. appsettings.Development.json, appsettings.Stage.json etc.

Comment: How do you run migrations to update database?

Comment: @GuruStron dotnet ef migrations add [migrationName] and dotnet ef database update. From the PM console on the DBContext Class library

Comment: I really don't know what injecting configuration has to do with migrations? Can you show your DI code? Using environment specific appsettings should be pretty straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can run update command and pass it the startup project (your ASP.NET Web API one) via `-s` or `--startup-project` (check out [common options in the CLI reference doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#common-options)). So from the root of the solution it can look like:

```bash
dotnet ef database update -p /PathToDbContextProj -s /PathToWebAPIProj
```

Or from the data project folder:

```bash
dotnet ef database update ../PathToWebAPIProj
```

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly inject an instance into your class that inherits from DbContext, e.g.

```cs
public class MyDatabaseDataContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public MyDatabaseDataContext(DbContextOptions<MyDatabase> dataContextOptions,
 IConfiguration configuration) : base(
        dataContextOptions)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    // Your DbSet declarations....etc
    public DbSet<Type> MySet { get; set; }
}
```

In your host process, you can initialise IConfiguration as normal, read from whichever sources you like, which might look something like

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
            {
                config.Sources.Clear();
                var env = context.HostingEnvironment;

                config
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.local.json", optional: true, true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            });
            
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
}
```

So, configure the reading of appsettings/env variables in the top level host process, make those setting values available on IConfiguration (or, a strongly typed object if you should wish) then inject that into your DbContext instance